# How to install the terra and raster libraries in R on Linux to manipulate .nc files?

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, ncdf4

I am trying to open and manipulate a .nc file (netcdf) in R. I have managed to install the ncdf4,RNetCDF, and ggplot2 packages. My issue is that when I try to install other packages to help me work with my files I get error messages such as "non zero exit status" (which I know means it was not installed), or a message about a package not being available for my version of R (I have 4.1.2).

I have tried to install the 'dependencies' listed in error messages first(after reading advice on here)-- but they won't install. I have typed an update command in my Linux terminal (which is how I got ncdf4 and RNetCDF to install). I have been searching all around online to find an answer--from GitHub, and directions from David W Peirce (who made ncview for Linux) and on this website--with no luck so far. I am not exactly sure how to operate with the ncdf4 library, but from my research I think I also need the raster library, the terra library, along with a few other libraries for spatial analysis.

My main issue is getting the raster and terra libraries to install. I have already tried:
install.packages("raster")
and
install.packages("raster", dependencies = TRUE)
and
install.packages("terra").

Part of my final error message reads:

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’

- removing ‘/home/******a/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/terra’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status

-Repeated with a bunch of littler packages such as "units" and "sf" and other things like that(which as I said earlier, I tried to install separately without success).
How do I get terra and raster to install?

Comment: Need FULL error messages, specifically the ones that say what dependencies are missing.

Comment: "I have tried to install the 'dependencies' listed in error messages first(after reading advice on here)-- but they won't install." - these are probably *system* dependencies you install into Linux rather than into R, using your Linux package manager. But hard to tell without seeing the errors and what you tried. eg units has "SystemRequirements:  udunits-2" and on my Linux box that needs `sudo apt install lib-udunits2-dev` or similar. Alternatively, set up r2u https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/ and get binary installs, with sys deps handled by apt magically.

Comment: How do you know you need the `terra` and `raster` packages? Your knowledge appears to be incomplete because `terra` is the successor to `raster` so you need one, not both. Why don't you tell us what it is that you want to do with your NetCDF files, there may be other solutions out there (such as the `stars` package).

Answer (score 2):

As @Barry mentions in the comment above, [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) can help you. It add to Ubuntu LTS system 20.04 and 22.04 the ability to query an `apt` repo with *all of CRAN* along with almost 400 BioConductor packages. Plus, by using `bspm` you can access this from R.

It works on standard Ubuntu laptop and servers, or in containers, or in GitHub Actions, or in the could -- it works whereever Ubuntu LTS run.

Here is a quick demo I just scree-recorded installing `terra` in one `install.packages("terra")` command -- resulting in *all fifty-plus required packages* being installed in seconds.  Give it a try!

[image]

(I didn't show `raster` becasue it is officially retired. [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) still has the binary.  So if you do `install.packages(c("terra", "raster"))` you get both.)